# Kubernetes service externalIPs not forwarding

Tags: ip, load-balancing, kubernetes

I have a Kubernetes cluster running 1.2.3 binaries along with flannel 0.5.5.  I am using the GCE backend with IP forwarding enabled.  For some reason, although I specify a specific Node's external IP address, it will not forward to the appropriate node.

Additionally I cannot create external load balancers, which the controller-manager says it can't find the gce instances that are the nodes, which are in ready state.  I've looked at the source where the load balancer creation happens, my guess is it's either permission issues (I gave the cluster full permissions for gce) or it's not finding the metadata.

Here is an example of the services in question:

```
kind: "Service"
apiVersion: "v1"
metadata:
  name: "client"
spec:
  ports:
    - protocol: "TCP"
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
      name: "insecure"
    - protocol: "TCP"
      port: 443
      targetPort: 443
      name: "secure"
  selector:
    name: "client"
  sessionAffinity: "ClientIP"
  externalIPs:
    - "<Node External IP>"
```

And when I was trying to create the load balancer, it had the `type: LoadBalancer`.

Why would the forwarding to the Node IP not work?  I have an idea as to the Load balancer issue, but if anyone has any insight?

Comment: You said you gave "the cluster full permissions for gce". Does that mean you have set compute permissions to “Read Write” for your VMs and added your SSH keys? Have you followed the instructions in this doc - https://coreos.com/flannel/docs/latest/gce-backend.html

Comment: @Madhusudan.C.S Yes to all of the above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I eventually worked around this issue by creating an external loadbalancer.  Only then did I have a valid external IP.